# Getting NullReferenceException while mocking Async method in Unit Test (Xunit - Moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq, xunit

I am having an issue while testing one of the service method which uses an async Repository method.

#### Repository layer

```cs
public interface IRepo
{
    Task<Model> GetByIdAsync(string Id);
    Task SaveAsync(Model model);
}
```

#### Service layer

```cs
void Process(string Id)
{
    var model = _repo.GetByIdAsync(Id).Result;
        
    model.Field1 = "update";
        
    _repo.SaveAsync(model).Wait();
}
```

#### Unit test against service layer

```cs
[Fact]
SUTServiceTest()
{
    //Arrange
    Model model = new Model();
    var mockRepo = Mock.Get(new Repo());

    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.GetByIdAsync(It.IsNotNull<string>()))
        .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(model));

    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.SaveAsync(It.IsAny<Model>()))
        .Callback<Model>((obj) => model = obj);

    var _service = new SUTService(mockRepo);

    //Act
    _service.Process("1");

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal("update", model.Field1);
}
```

I'm  getting the following error at `_repo.SaveAsync(model).await();`:

> System.NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Not sure what did I miss.

Comment: Can you share with us please the `.await()` implementation as well?

Comment: @PeterCsala in the test i am setting up the mock for the awaited method. 

but for reference below is the implementation

`public async Task repoAsync(Model model)
{
    await dbHelper.SaveAsync(model).ConfigureAwait(false);
}`

Comment: I'm interested about this await: `_repo.SaveAsync(model).await();` in the Service layer.

Comment: Yes, I had mis-typed the method name - 

`public async Task SaveAsync(Model model) {     await dbHelper.SaveAsync(model).ConfigureAwait(false); }`

in any case, we are mocking the method so not sure if that would affect the test code.

Comment: Could you please update your question accordingly?

Comment: The Question has correct code, in comment i had written method name as `repoAsync`  which should be `SaveAsync`

Comment: Then please tell us what does this `.await()` method do in this line: `_repo.SaveAsync(model).await();` It is not a .NET built-in function, right?

Comment: My Bad again, It was `.Wait();` that awaits for the thread to return after executing.

Comment: Change this line: `var mockRepo = Mock.Get(new Repo());` to this: `var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();`

Comment: @PeterCsala That works. Thanks.. However, I loose the DI setup that I have for Repo construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent behind this answer is to capture valuable information from the chat discussion.

As the OP said a `NullReferenceException` has been thrown at the following line:

```cs
_repo.SaveAsync(model).Wait();
```

The `_repo` tried to be initialized in the following way in the unit test:

```cs
var mockRepo = Mock.Get(new Repo());
```

That's not the correct way to do it. Please check the [documentation](https://documentation.help/Moq/C6B12927.htm) of the `Mock.Get` to know when it should be used and for what purpose.

The `_repo` should be initialized in the following way:

```cs
var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();
```

---

The OP had the following observation after changing the mock creation:

> However, I loose the DI setup that I have for Repo construction

In short: That's the whole point.
Whenever you are unit testing a component then you try to mock out (simplify and mimic) all of its dependencies. It needs to rely on **stubs** and **spies** to be able to verify which one of them have been called under certain circumstances but the concrete implementation of the mocked objects do not matter.

In this particular case that means that the Service layer do not want to rely on a concrete Repository instance. It needs only a repo, which can capture the calling parameters and which can verify its calling.

---

FYI: Testing [terminologies](https://blog.pragmatists.com/test-doubles-fakes-mocks-and-stubs-1a7491dfa3da)

- **Dummy**: simple code that returns **bogus** data
- **Fake**: a working **alternative** which can take shortcuts
- **Stub**: custom logic with **predefined** data
- **Mock**:  custom logic with **expectations** (interactive stub)
- **Shim**: custom logic **at run-time**
- **Spy**: **interceptors** to record calls